# Cannot assign this CGFloat to a property in XCode using Swift

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, nsview

I'm trying to set the thickness of a divider of a NSSplitView to a specified CGFloat value but I get the error: "Cannot assign to the result of this expression error in Swift".

I do it this way and it seems like correct, what do you think is wrong with that?

[image: i.stack.imgur.com/2ylKS.png]

`splitView.dividerThickness` is a CGFloat value as you can see in picture 2.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property is *read-only*:

```
 var dividerThickness: CGFloat { get }
```

so you cannot assign a new value. The documentation states:

> You can subclass `NSSplitView` and override this method to change the thickness of a split view’s dividers.

Comment: That was stupid so, didn't notice that! Sorry. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to be clear enough to fix it : `dividerThickness` requires a `Float` and not a `CGFloat`.

In order to fix it, you can :

- Declare your value like so : `var val : Float = 0.0`
- Keep your value as a CGFloat, and then use the Float() initializer : `spitView.dividerThickness = Float(val)`

That's because `CGFloat` has different size on 32bit and 64bit machines.

*Unfortunately, the cast isn't done automatically. But you might be able to find (or write your own) operator overloading.*

Comment: Sorry but it does not solve the problem, it's so strange. I've added another picture, you see the type is not a Float but a CGFloat.

Comment: I haven't checked from where you were using the `dividerThickness` property. The _problem_ is that the property is read-only.

Comment: @Ichamp yes, my fault sorry!